# Way to fetch function name in fallback function with Solidity

Tags: solidity, fallback-function

I am writing a fallback function this way:

```
fallback() external {        
     (param1, param2) = abi.decode(msg.data[4:], (uint256, uint256));
}
```

I know this is not a good practice but let's suppose i call an "azerty" function on my contract with 2 uint256. And of course, azerty function does not exists. So fallback function will be called.

I have 2 questions inside this fallback function:

- How can i get the function name (azerty) ?
- Is there a way to get the arguments types and count ? (in my case, i know i have 2 uint256 but what will happen if i call azerty with a single uint argument ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to recover the function name from the transaction alone since only 4 bytes from the function identifier are include. Those 4 bytes are also accessible through `msg.sig`.

It should be possible to store a mapping in the contract so they can be recovered from the identifier: `mapping (bytes4 => string) public signatures`. Store them `signatures[bytes4(0x70a08231)] = "balanceOf(address)"`, using it `signatures[msg.sig]`.

Recent solidity version validate a function has enough data and revert if they have less than expected.

Using fallback skips any validation but `abi.decode` fails when there's not enough data to decode all of its parameters.